# Bound Variable and Free Variable, A Questions and one Example?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I see a Local Contest Question as :

for statement $ \forall x [ \exists y ( x<y+z) \to \exists z (x < y+z)] $ two following axiom is True:

> I) $ y, z$ is free and $x$ is bounded.
>
> II) $x,y,z$ is bounded.

I think just (I) is True. Who can inspect it very carefully with complete proof?

Comment: Yes; the *scope* of the outer $\forall x$ is all the formula : $[ \ldots]$, and thus all occurrences of $x$ in the formula are bound. $z$ is *free* in the LH subformula : $∃y(x<y+z)$, while $y$ is *free* in the RH $∃z(x<y+z)$; thus both variables $y,z$ have *free* occurrences in the complete formula.

Comment: you means My inference is true or question ? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Statement I) is true.

Answer (score 0):

The first $z$ is free and the second $y$ is free. The rest are bounded.

So it's neither because one instance of "z" is bounded and another isn't. If statement I read "There are variables called $x$ and $y$ which are unbounded" or statement II read "There are variables called $x$, $y$ and $z$ which are bounded", then it would be unambiguous. I don't see how you can choose between statements I and II.

Comment: The correct terminology is "bound variable". There is such a thing as a "bounded quantifier", which is different.

Comment: @CarlMummert thanks when again I see the question this is not say variable. I edit my question. it seems just (I) is Right? Ok ?